# In a method call hierarchy from different process which application will dump core

Tags: objective-c, operating-system, synchronization

Say there is an process which has a method mthd1 (written in C/C++) which calls another method mthd2 of another process in shared memory environment and there "OCCURED" something that led to the core dump at mthd2.
So is it the process that has initiated the call , mthd1, that will dump core or is there anything else that will determine which process will dump the core.
I am really confused about it.

Thanks
Ankit

Comment: Did the process which has mtd1 start the process that has mtd2?  The answer to your question depends on this.

Comment: No. The processes are running independently and there is only communication between them. @CraigS.Anderson